Other way to pronounce they'd
Is there another way to pronounce the word "they'd"? In this video (2:23), I think he pronounces it as "/ðed/ instead of /ðeɪd/.
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXQQ94rg9ic
Thank you!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The pronunciation of they'd in the video is /ðeɪd/, not an alternate pronunciation. You may need to practice distinguishing the sounds in raid and red.

I taught English language in Japan. English was my favorite course study and is indeed one of the most difficult languages to learn.
They'd would be pronounced sounding like "theid". Depending on the sentence structure it could mean "they did" or "they would".
Not sure I'm answering your question or merely contemplating it.

There is no other pronunciation for "they'd" than /ðeɪd/, whether in BrE or AmE. This is the pronunciation used by the speaker, but the second part of the diphthong is only faintly heard.

(Cambridge Dictionary) they’d
How to pronounce "they’d"
UK/ðeɪd/
US/ðeɪd/

This is also the only pronunciation in Longman Pronunciation Dictionary (J C Wells).
In normal speech the sound is weaker; this can be heard in the spoken sentences of a pronunciation model on You Tube; the sound of the second vowel in /eɪ/ becomes much attenuated when found in a full sentence; it is barely audible.

How to pronounce "they'd" in English 


In several dialects including Indian, Irish, Chicano, and some African and south Pacific, /eɪ/ is realised as [eː], [e], [ɛ:] or [ɛ]. There's also a date/day split in parts of northern England where the former is [e], [ɛ] or similar and the latter [eɪ]. See e.g. this.

@StuartF There are also multiple regions across the US with monophthong [e] and [o] in many positions that are not at the end of the word. It's commonly heard in Minnesota and Wisconsin, but not limited to those regions.

If teachers had to cover every single pronunciation for every single thing, students could not learn to speak English.

@Lambie Listen carefulelly to the UK speaker in the reference: no short vowel /e/ but whatever the type (single sound or diphthong) a long vowel; it is my definite impression that this is not the short vowel /e/ that has been elongated but instead the diphthong /eɪ/ in which the second sound is very faint. // I agree with you: you can't cover every single sound in the classroom—an expert's problem in modern days—wherefrom the need for standards. (1/2)

@Lambie    How do you explain that the next answer, which is a plain repetition of what I say (no references at all), gets a +1 when my answer gets a - 4 (I guess you've added your "-1" for some obscure reason)? (2/2)

I didn't downvote. The guy is just speaking fast. Of course, it's ðeɪd. I have no idea about the other answer or even most things around here.

@Lambie I beg you pardon for my rashness then; sometimes, you know, one would rather know.

You need to be more careful on that othe site.

@Lambie What do you mean? The FSE? As far as goes the content of my answers, well, yes, I find they contain too many mistakes, but otherwise? I am not saying anything to anyone, not that I wouln't have any ground for doing that. // it's "your pardon" above, skipped the r somehow)

@Lambie There is nothing silly about my comments; he is merely aware of the pertinence of my analogy_the debate on the SE sites_are_ according to some sort of democratic process, no doubt_, and an easy thing to do in the way of an answer is to make me look like a pretentious fool (he is a politician, not of the best sort, I should say). Not having on the page the exact words of what he asked you I still don't know what it is; I believe it was the English for the two paragraphs you wrote, but I don't have his words, I can't be sure.
